# Ads not showing in windows 10 uwp

Tags: c#, uwp, ads

I have a UWP app that uses ads, but even after being published for 2 days, the ads are not showing in the app. Heres what my XAML code looks like:

```
<ad:AdControl ApplicationId="9nwcrqc0ll9j"
                         AdUnitId="1100053237"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         Height="250"
                         Width="300" RenderTransformOrigin="0.559,0.484"/>
```

And heres what it says on my UWP dev dashboard: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RG0a.jpg

As you can see, I have the correct adunitId, and appid, but the adds are not showing. when I put 'test' in for the adunitid, then a test ad shows, but with actual values and published in the store, nothing shows. Does anyone know why?

Comment: I have just added an ad banner exactly like you did and mine are showing correctly.

Comment: Maybe that RenderTransformOrigin property shouldn’t be set?

Comment: I tested your ApplicationId in my side, the AdRefreshed method will not invoke, may your ApplicationId  not active, please try other ApplicationId. For more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/adcontrol-in-xaml-and--net).

Comment: Please try handling the `AdControl.ErrorOccured` event to see what kind of error is reported. It is possible there is no ad available to fill the banner. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.advertising.winrt.ui.adcontrol.erroroccurred

Comment: @LucaLindholml, I test it again, the ApplicationId  available now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ads not showing in windows 10 uwp

Base on the testing, your `ApplicationId` is just getting started. It is available now. Please check official document.

> If you have created an ad recently (less than a day), it might not be available immediately. If the ad has been approved for editorial content, it will be served once the advertising server has processed it and the ad is available as inventory.

As Martin Zikmund said , you could use [`ErrorOccured`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.advertising.winrt.ui.adcontrol.erroroccurred) event to see what kind of error is reported. For more please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/known-issues-for-the-advertising-libraries#recently-created-ads-are-not-being-served-to-your-app)